# i can't see crash report of android in firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, crashlytics

1) I implement firebase crashlytics in my react native project.

2) I used below npm

- npm install @react-native-firebase/app@alpha
- react-native link @react-native-firebase/app
- npm install @react-native-firebase/crashlytics@alpha
- react-native link @react-native-firebase/crashlytics

3) I can do crash app by programmatically using

async forceCrash() {

```
       firebase.crashlytics().crash();

       await firebase.crashlytics().setAttributes({ something: 
             "something" });

       firebase.crashlytics().log("A woopsie is incoming :(");

       firebase.crashlytics().recordError(new Error("Error Log"));
```

}

- but i can't error log report in firabase console.

  - Please give me your value able suggestion. where i am  wrong.

Comment: Check https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/crashlytics/android and follow all steps

Answer (score 1):

React native is not officially supported but developers have been able to use crashlytics with React native. From your snippet of code, it seems that you are try trying make a test crash and send a non-fatal exception at the same time.

If you want to see logs on your crash report, the code should look something like this:

```
Crashlytics.log("Crash occurred! Bailing out...");
```

Make sure that you set these logs before your app crashes.

If you want to send non-fatal exception:

```
try {
        throw new NullPointerException("It is Pointer No-Fatal Error");

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Crashlytics.logException(e);

        // handle your exception here!
    }
```

Logs will also appear with non-fatal exceptions as long as they were set before the exception occurs.